# AngularJS - update model from outside the ng-repeat loop

Tags: angularjs

I'm fairly new to Angular so apologies if my use of terminology is a bit off.

Here's the view code:

```
<main ng-controller="DataController">

    <table id="table">
        <tbody>

            <tr ng-repeat="movie in movies | filter:name | orderBy:field:reverse" ng-click="select(movie.name,movie.rating)">
                <td>{{movie.name}}</td>
                <td>{{movie.rating}}</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>

    <form ng-submit="submit()" id="form" method="post">

        <label for="item">Item:</label>
        <input type="text" name="item" ng-model="selecteditem"/>

        <select ng-model="rating" name="rating">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">
    </form>

</main>
```

Notice the form lives outside of the ng-repeat loop. Here's a pen: http://codepen.io/nomis101uk/pen/WvaKyY

Basically I want to be able to click a film, then change its rating with the select. Problem is, with the form living outside the ng-repeat loop, the binding on the select element would have to dynamically change to match whatever film I click. I can't simply say ng-model="movie.rating", because Angular won't know which film I'm referring to.

This could be solved by putting the form inside the loop, but that would result in my view being populated a massive quantity of forms. Definitely not a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having what I imagine is:

```
$scope.select = function(title, rating) {...};
```

why not

```
$scope.select = function(movie) {
    ... do something with movie.title and movie.rating ...
    $scope.selectedMovie = movie;
};
```

then

change

```
<tr ng-repeat="movie in movies | filter:name | orderBy:field:reverse" ng-click="select(movie.name,movie.rating)">
                <td>{{movie.name}}</td>
                <td>{{movie.rating}}</td>
            </tr>
```

to

```
<tr ng-repeat="movie in movies | filter:name | orderBy:field:reverse" ng-click="select(movie)">
                <td>{{movie.name}}</td>
                <td>{{movie.rating}}</td>
            </tr>
```

and in your select use `selectedMovie.rating`

Answer (score 0):

Well you can make something like this...

**HTML**
Change this line from

```
<tr ng-repeat="movie in movies | filter:name | orderBy:field:reverse" ng-click="select(movie.name,movie.rating)">
```

to

```
<tr ng-repeat="movie in movies | filter:name | orderBy:field:reverse" ng-click="select($index)">
```

**JS**

```
$scope.select = function(selectedIndex) {
    SelectedItemService.selectedItem = selectedIndex;
    movies[selectedIndex]['rating'] += 1
}

$scope.submit = function() {
    var selectedIndex = SelectedItemService.selectedItem;
}

angular.service('SelectedItemService', function() {
    this.selectedItem
});
```

Comment: GPicazos answer ist better then mine for your purpose... My answer is the way if you also need the selected item in another controller....